# Oracle PIVOT with subquery (without XML clause)

Tags: oracle, pivot

Oracle 19.3 on Win2019
Looking for a solution to pivot data based on the subquery. I looked for examples, but all I found is the "pivot xml" solution, which returns xml-formated column.
Here is my query:

```
with assign_data as
(
select --*
    style_id
    ,color_id
    ,size_id
    ,in_whse_date
    ,sum(pd2_assign_so_quantity) qty
from pd2_assignment
where business_unit_id = '81'
  and style_id = 'Y186F3D'
  and color_id = '035Y'
  and property_mark = '8FQR'
group by
    style_id
    ,color_id
    ,size_id
    ,in_whse_date
order by size_id
)
select * from assign_data
pivot XML (
    sum(qty) for (in_whse_date) in ( select distinct in_whse_date from assign_data)
    )
```

Inner query produces this:

[image]

Pivot XML produces this:

[image]

Question: Is it possible to generate PIVOT with columns from a subquery that are not in xml format?
If not, is there another way to simulate this pivot behavior?

Comment: Oracle does not support having a dynamic set of values in the `IN` clause of a `PIVOT` statement. You can do this when doing an `XML PIVOT` because the values will be returned in one column. Having a dynamic list in the `IN` clause would cause the query to have a different number of columns based on what is in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Check out Anton's tool for this https://technology.amis.nl/it/pivot-dynamic-data/